# What is the type of Error object in HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular6

In `Angular` documentation (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse), the `HttpErrorResponse` is suppose to contain the error.

Question 1 -  I notice that if the server sends `json` then the `error` property contains that `json`. Is it that `Angular` is copying the `body` into `error` property?

Question 2 - The document also says `The error property will contain either a wrapped Error object or the error response returned from the server.` What is this `Error object`? Is it some type defined in Angular? In my code, I'll like to print the `error` property but I can't esp. for non-server related errors. In such cases, I don't know the type of `error`.

Comment: Wow, it's been 8 months and no answer.